# Protecting main thread from errors in worker thread

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, signals, posix

When using posix threads, is there some way to "protect" the main thread from errors (such as dereferenced null pointers, division by zero, etc) caused by worker threads. By "worker thread" I mean a posix thread created by pthread_create().

Unfortunately, we cannot use exceptions - so no "catch", etc.

Here is my test program (C++):

```
void* workerThreadFunc(void* threadId) {
  int* a = NULL;
  *a = 5; //Error (segmentation fault)
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  cout << "Main thread start" << endl;

  pthread_t workerThread;
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  pthread_create(&workerThread, &attr, workerThreadFunc, (void*)0);
  pthread_join(workerThread, NULL);

  cout << "Main thread end" << endl;
}
```

In the example above, the error caused by workerThread will terminate the whole program. But I would like the main thread to continue running despite this error. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: 'Unfortunately, we cannot use exceptions - so no "catch", etc.' - sure you can.  The exception will be thrown in the thread that raised it.

Comment: The best way to 'protect' other threads from exceptions/errors it to fix them so they don't happen or are detected and handled/logged/whatever.

Comment: Note - in your example above, you are trying to join a thread that has not been created yet.

Comment: @MartinJames Ah yes you're right, thanks. Although it was just a simple mistake when copying the lines to my example (my real program runs in the correct order). I'll edit my post.

Comment: @MartinJames " sure you can. The exception will be thrown in the thread that raised it". Our code will need to be compiled for a system with no exception support.

Comment: How is the program terminated by the worker thread? Does it call exit or use some interrupt?

Comment: Oh, no exception support, OK:(

Comment: You can use a `signal` handler to catch signals sent to the process (provided there is support for signals).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be using multiple processes, not threads. Independent processes are automatically protected from these sort of errors happening in other processes.

You can use pipes or shared memory (or other forms of IPC) to pass data between threads, which has the additional benefit of only sharing the memory you intend to share, so a bug in the worker "thread" cannot stomp on the stack of the main "thread", because it's a separate process with a separate address space.

Threads can be useful, but come with several disadvantages, sometimes running in separate processes is more appropriate.

Comment: By "process" you mean for example fork()?

Comment: Yes, `fork()` new child processes from the master, and either `exec()` a different executable for the workers, or just keep running the same executable but have the children run in "worker" mode.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can think of doing this is registering a signal handler, which could instead of aborting the program, cancel the currently running thread, something like this:

```
void handler(int sig)
{
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
```

Note, however, this is unsafe as `pthread_exit` isn't listed as one of the safe system calls inside a signal handler. It might work and it might not, depending on the O/S you're running under, and on what signal you're handling.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do the trick, at least for now in a simple test. I will need to research the safety issues you talk about.

Comment: It seems like pthread_exit cause a SIGABRT if an object has been created on that threads stack and that object has a destructor defined. This will either cause an infinite loop of caught SIGABRT's (if catching them in the sighandler), or else a complete program crash. This happens for example if I declare an object of a very simple struct. It will crash if that object has a destructor defined, even just ~A() {}. But without this destructor defined, no SIGABRT is sent. The problem also happens if I declare for example a vector<int>.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your system uses signals in a POSIX sort of a way (though that may fall under the "no exceptions" rule), then POSIX says:

> At the time of generation, a determination shall be made whether the signal has been generated for the process or for a specific thread within the process. Signals which are generated by some action attributable to a particular thread, such as a hardware fault, shall be generated for the thread that caused the signal to be generated.

So you can handle `SIGSEGV`, `SIGFPE`, etc. on a per pthread basis (but note that you can only set one signal handler function for the entire process).  So, you can "protect" the process from being stopped dead by a failure in a single pthread... up to a point.  The problem, of course, is that you may find it very difficult to tell what state the process -- the failed pthread, and all the other pthreads -- is in.  The failed pthread may be holding a number of mutexes.  The failed pthread may be leaving some shared data structure(s) in a mess.  Who knows what sort of a tangle things are in -- unless the pthreads are essentially independent.  It may be possible to arrange for other pthreads to close down "gracefully"... rather than crash and burn.  It may, in the end, be safer to stop all pthreads dead, rather than try to continue in some less than well defined state.  It will depend entirely on the nature of the application.

Nothing is for nothing... threads can communicate with each other more easily than processes, and cost less to start and stop -- processes are less vulnerable to failure of other processes.